# ... yet another issue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

Occasionally when posting a comment I find that the @username that I generally put at the start gets dropped when I save it. This is normally correctable by editing and re-saving the comment. Somewhat annoying but not the end of the world.

Tonight I was posting a comment to [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/433923/9278) and despite twice editing and re-saving it, the "@Frerich" that I was trying to put at the beginning just kept getting dropped. I gave up at that point.

Using Google Chrome version 22.0.1229.79 on OS X 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion), with all updates applied.

Comment: This is not a bug; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation

Comment: dammit, Mark, one single second.

Comment: Wtf meta auto converted my answer to a comment!! Now THAT is annoying

Comment: @MarkHenderson, yes, that's also by-design, as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment) - and also managed to confuse another mod [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107063/how-could-a-user-with-1-reputation-point-leave-a-comment/107064#107064)

Comment: Ok, it's not a bug but that just means it's really poor and unfriendly design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This, to the best of my knowledge, is actually [by-design](/questions/tagged/by-design). In [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) MSO thread, it says that as you could only be replying to the person that asked the question (in your example) then the @Username is stripped out automatically. If you can fully understand that answer in its entirety I would be more than impressed as it's not exactly clear.

Comment: I'm sure you'll understand if I don't bother to read anything that justifies such absurd design. Thanks for the answer. Of course that doesn't explain why I can normally edit the name back in.

Comment: And now I have to wait another minute before I can accept your answer. Gotta love devs who understand UI design. :/

Comment: To be honest, I don't think it's justifiable, apart from "to reduce clutter and noise" or to save some precious database bytes.